# Store/Share data with a container in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've dockerized a python project that requires the use of several CSVs (~2gb). In order to keep image size down I didn't include the CSVs in the build, instead opting to give the running container the data from a directory outside the container through a volume. Locally, when running through docker, I can just do

```
docker run -v ~/local/path/:/container/path my-image:latest
```

This works, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this in Kubernetes. I've been reading the documentation and am confused by the number of volume types, where the actual CSVs should be stored, etc.

Based on the information about the project that I've provided, is there an obvious solution?

Comment: Are these csv files static files? Or they change during runtime.  If they are mostly static files my first intuition would be to include it inside the image.
Since they are big i would consider compressing it and adding it to the container.  And in the docker entrypoint, i will extract it to a location.  The consequence is that the startup time would be slower.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to replicate that exact behavior from Docker the most common way to do it is to use [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath). Something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: my-image:latest
    name: my-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /container/path
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      path: /usr/local/path
      type: Directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical example of sharing between containers. You can keep your data in a separate container and code in a different container.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html

  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

Hope it helps.